# Unable to Read keys form YAML

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bean-validation

I am new to Spring Boot and I am trying to read validation messages from  `application.yml` but unable to do so

here my Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_data")
public class User {

    @NotBlank(message = "${errorresponse.useridMissing}")
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

 public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

My Config class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("errorresponse")
public class ErrorResponsesConfig {


private  String useridMissing ;

public String getMissingValue() {
    return useridMissing;
}

public void setMissingValue(String useridMissing) {
    this.useridMissing = useridMissing;
}
```

}

`application.yml` looks like this

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
errorresponse:
   useridMissing: Please provide UserID
```

but values are not being read when validation fails during bean validation

When I run unit test it gives me following exception

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ELResolver cannot handle a null base Object with identifier 'errorresponse'
at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.throwUnhandled(ELSupport.java:42) ~[jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:100) ~[jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:125) ~[jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173) ~[jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:183) ~[jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.ElTermResolver.interpolate(ElTermResolver.java:67) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.interpolate(InterpolationTerm.java:64) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:159) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.AbstractMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(AbstractMessageInterpolator.java:519) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.AbstractMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(AbstractMessageInterpolator.java:415) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.AbstractMessageInterpolator.interpolate(AbstractMessageInterpolator.java:355) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator.interpolate(LocaleContextMessageInterpolator.java:51) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.validationcontext.AbstractValidationContext.interpolate(AbstractValidationContext.java:313) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.validationcontext.AbstractValidationContext.addConstraintFailure(AbstractValidationContext.java:230) ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
```

Please guide me what am I doing wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation or i18n messages you shouldn't manage in application.yml. In Java/Spring applications you should use properties files for this and the syntax is in your models without $:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{email.notempty}")
@Email
private String email;
```

For more informations check this tutorial: [Custom Validation MessageSource in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-validation-message-source)

Comment: followed the link, but its still not working,
no error or exception and still doesnot pick it

Comment: JSON path errors doesn't match.
Expected: iterable containing ["Please provide UserId"]
  Actual: [{errorresponse.useridMissing}]..................

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path errors doesn't match
Expected: iterable containing ["Please provide UserId"]
  Actual: [{errorresponse.useridMissing}]

Comment: Actually i was missing @Configuratoin on source configuration class, its working.
Thanks